# Remember when summer days felt like they would go on forever?

Tags: grammar

What is the difference between the following sentence?

> Remember when summer days felt like they would go on forever?
>
> Remember when summer days we felt like they would go on forever?

Answer (score 3):

The difference is that:

> 1. Remember when summer days felt like they would go on forever?

is correct while

> 2. *Remember when summer days we felt like they would go on forever?

is not.

The point is that in (1) the subject of the embedded clause starting with "when" is "summer days": summer days felt like (were perceived as if) they would go on forever.

Instead, (2) does not make sense as written, because the subject of the embedded clause is "we". A possible sentence (though slightly different in meaning) could be:

> 3. Remember when **on** summer days we felt like they (summer days) would go on forever?

(3) is not a good sentence, though. I'd prefer (4):

> 4. Remember when we felt like summer days would go on forever?

Comment: Thanks so much. Do you think "Remember summer days when they both felt like they were going to go on forever?" Is OK as well?

Comment: What do you want the second "they" to refer to: the summer days or the people involved?

Comment: Who is being requested to remember these summer days? Not 'they', logically.

Comment: @MichaelHarvey Unless "go on" means "go on with their relationship". In that case we could say:  "Remember those summer days when they both felt like they were going to go on forever?"

Comment: @Gustavson "They" refers to "summer days" . "Remember summer days when they felt like they were going to go on forever?"

Comment: @samsam You could say: Remember **the** summer days when they felt like they were going to go on forever?